Schema changes after postgresql is installed with Helm
I'm creating a small Helm chart. It has:

a dependency on postgresql
a small application that run the db schema migrations
a little service with a REST API that depends on that fully migrated database

I would like to make sure that my DB migrations are executed after the postgresql dependency is installed, but before my service is deployed.
The following is my Chart.yaml:
apiVersion: v2
name: apicentral
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes

# A chart can be either an 'application' or a 'library' chart.
#
# Application charts are a collection of templates that can be packaged into versioned archives
# to be deployed.
#
# Library charts provide useful utilities or functions for the chart developer. They're included as
# a dependency of application charts to inject those utilities and functions into the rendering
# pipeline. Library charts do not define any templates and therefore cannot be deployed.
type: application

# This is the chart version. This version number should be incremented each time you make changes
# to the chart and its templates, including the app version.
# Versions are expected to follow Semantic Versioning (https://semver.org/)
version: 0.1.0

# This is the version number of the application being deployed. This version number should be
# incremented each time you make changes to the application. Versions are not expected to
# follow Semantic Versioning. They should reflect the version the application is using.
# It is recommended to use it with quotes.
appVersion: '1.16.0'

dependencies:
  - name: postgresql
    version: "16.0.1"
    repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"

and the following is my db-migrations.yaml file. I have been trying to create a helm hook to make it happen.
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "apicentral-db-migrate-{{ now | unixEpoch }}"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "0"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
spec:
  backoffLimit: 5
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 300
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: apicentral-db-migrate
          image: "{{ .Values.apicentral.postgres.schemaMigrationApp }}"
          args:
            - "/app/index.js"
            - "up"
            - "-h"
            - "{{ .Values.apicentral.postgres.host }}"
            - "-p"
            - "{{ .Values.apicentral.postgres.port }}"
            - "-d"
            - "{{ .Values.apicentral.postgres.database }}"
            - "-u"
            - "{{ .Values.apicentral.postgres.username }}"
            - "-P"
            - "{{ .Values.apicentral.postgres.password }}"

At the moment the hook is running before anything else, which is not optimal


... my DB migrations are executed after the postgresql dependency is installed, but before my service is deployed

Helm can't do this level of ordering.  If you read through the documentation on Chart Hooks, you can set something to run before absolutely everything else (pre-install/pre-upgrade) or after absolutely everything else (post-install/post-uprade), but not in the middle in a specific order.
I'd do this by just removing the hook annotations entirely, and letting Helm toss everything into the cluster.  Change the Job to restartPolicy: OnFailure.  Kubernetes will create the Pods and they'll start trying to run.  When the migration Job starts before the database StatefulSet, it will fail, and Kubernetes will retry it with backoff; similarly, when the application starts up and its tables aren't there, it will crash and the cluster will restart it.  Eventually the database will be up and the Job will be able to run successfully, and then after that the application will come up.
The one other potential option here is to treat the database like an infrastructure service and install it separately.  (In reality I've used cloud-hosted out-of-cluster databases, and I've also heard complaints about needing to manage a separate database per service.)  If you create a database outside of this sequence and pass its host name and credentials as Helm values, then "before anything else" becomes the time when you do want to run the migrations, and a pre-install hook would be right.

yeah... I figured that if that was a thing, I would have found it by now from the docs. I don't really like this approach :/ Call me old fashioned AWS nerd, but I feel like a successful deployment shouldn't lead to any errors :/ Of course, once I deploy the whole thing to the cloud, I will be using a DB from outside of k8s, but that makes it more difficult for other devs to just test your chart. Services like keycloak come with their postgres, that you can just opt-out from. I was hoping to go in that direction...

i kinda solved it for now with "helm.sh/hook": post-install,pre-upgrade

You can make a dependency optional and "container in dev, RDS in production" has worked well for me in the past.  But the specific ordering problem you're running into is harder to address if the database is only maybe a Kubernetes dependency.
